# Automatically upload table to database

Tags: php, mysql, web-scraping

How can I automatically upload to a database data from tables like the one in this [page](http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201506160CLE.html)? I can use their function "export" and then manually download the .csv file, and upload it, but if I want everyday the data from each game, it is a pain... do you think it is possible to automatize it? The only solution would be by scraping their website?

Thanks

Comment: do they have an API?

Comment: scraping violates their terms of use "Please do not attempt to spider data from our web sites, as spidering violates the terms and conditions that govern your use of our web sites"

Comment: That's why I don't want to! And I'm asking for other solutions... ;) No there are no APIs!

Comment: then i think you are out of luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php) lib of PHP.

Here there's an example:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0; // set to zero for no timeout
    $url = 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201506160CLE.html'; // set the page url
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);//enter your url here
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch); //get the page contents
    include "simple_html_dom.php";
    $table = $file_contents;
    $html = str_get_html($table);
    $printing = false;
    //header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
    $fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach($html->find('tr') as $element){
        $arr = array();
        foreach ($element->find('tr') as $element2) {
                    if(!$printing)
                        $printing = strpos($element2,'Scoring') !== false;
                    if($printing){
                        //echo $element2 -> plaintext . "<br>";
                        $arr[] = $element2 -> plaintext; //comment here
                    }

        }
        fputcsv($fp, $arr);
        }

        fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

You have to download a file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/).
You get a text/csv file in your page, if you prefere a plain it's sufficient switch comments (comment line where is requested and decomment the others)

You can parse your new csv as you want

Comment: Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: Of course! I edited my post